# API to obtain open and click rates of recipient lists in Sendgrid

Tags: api, smtp, statistics, sendgrid

In Sendgrid, when viewing the recipient lists, it shows the open and click rates of each of the individual lists. Is there an API I can use to get those values? I tried using the Stats API but it shows per day, not per list. So is there an API to show the rates of each list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not currently a way to do this through the API. Your best bet to get this one the roadmap is to start a discussion on our community board [(http://community.sendgrid.com/)](http://community.sendgrid.com/).

You can also always reach out to our support team for questions like this!